# How do you link to the options page in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension with an [options page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/options.html).  The options page works correctly and I can get to it from the extensions page, however I'd also like a link to it  within the popup of my extension.  Is this possible?  It doesn't seem to have a url but is there a way to tell chrome to link to the extensions options?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can have Chrome open your extension's options page in a new tab using something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': "/options.html" } )
```

Much like HTML, the URL is considered relative to the calling page, but you can use a forward slash to load a page that is relative to the extension's root.

*update:*

If you want to open the options page from content-script you have to use this method: 
[How do you open Chrome extension options page from a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946346/how-do-you-open-chrome-extension-options-page-from-a-web-page)

Comment: I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined` in a **[content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)**. Looks like [I can't do that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script). I also can't upvote you unless the answer is edited again.

Comment: You can send a message from your content script to a background page if you want to avoid adding web accessible resources to your manifest file.  Using messages is probably more in line with how extensions were originally designed.

Answer (score 40):

New method since Chrome 42:

[`chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-openOptionsPage) will open the options, regardless of whether new-style embedded options or old-style options page is used.

> `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()` will always open the canonical location, and has nice behavior like re-focusing an open options page if there is one.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I was about to run into the incorrect documentation about the new style of options.

Comment: It's so strange that the documentation server did not pick up the documentation update (which is already in the codebase) for 3 weeks. I pinged kalman about it.

Comment: Worth noting is that this doesn't seem to work from embedded elements like buttons.

Comment: @BradJohnson Perhaps you're trying to use inline `onclick`, which is not allowed.

Comment: I built the button using document.createElement and attached click event listener.  No joy.

Comment: @BradJohnson If that's UI injected by a content script, then indeed `chrome.runtime.openOptionsPage()` is not available from the content script context. Alternatively, you may be using a `submit` button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a relative link directly in the html:

```
<a href="options.html" target="_blank">Options</a>
```

Comment: This wont work, especially if this has been embedded in into a webpage. At that point it take the default domain and prefixes it to options.html. Ex: `localhost/options.html` You want `Chrome-extension://sfj2jngijnei2f9b2f9bbkbe/options.html` which can only be obtained via the chrome API. chrome.extension.getURL('options.html')