# "Cannot read property of undefined" when using chrome.tabs or other chrome API in content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

`chrome.tabs` returns undefined despite the fact I set tabs in the permissions block.

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "http://*/*",
            "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js": [
            "js/myScript.js"
        ],
        "all_frames": true
    }
],
```

But in `myScript.js`, `chrome.tabs` is `undefined`.

Comment: `chrome.tabs` is only available to code which runs in the extension's process, such as the background, options or popup page. Content scripts cannot access the `chrome.tabs` object.

Comment: I have chrome.tabs inside a background page and it is undefined also

Answer (score 110, accepted):

[Content script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts) can only use chrome.`i18n`, chrome.`dom`, chrome.`storage`, and a subset of chrome.`runtime`/chrome.`extension`.

Most `chrome` APIs such as `chrome.tabs` are only available the background script (service worker in MV3), popup script, etc.

#### Solution

[Pass a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) from the content script to the [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/) and use the API there.

Comment: It's a little confusing that the API docs for [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi) includes instructions about using the `chrome.tabs` API...

Comment: I'm vote down this, because I got absolute opposite doc from google official api docs.  >chrome.tabs.getCurrent  >Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example: a background page or popup view).  Please check this :https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent

Comment: chrome.tabs is always undef for me

Comment: This is simply not true.  `chrome.tabs` is undefined in popup scripts.

Comment: Just to add - I have tried using `debugger`s before `chrome.tabs` calls within a `background` page, and that's when I get `chrome.tabs` to be `undefined`. When I run that code without interruption, it seems to work fine (again, only within the `background` page)

Comment: @VicX you're right but the Chrome Developer documentation is frequently out of date or incorrect. This may be one of those cases.

Answer (score 22):

[Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/content-scripts) have only limited access to Chrome APIs.  This access does not include the API  you are trying to use (e.g. `chrome.tabs`). If you need to use that API, you will have to do so in a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)<sup>1</sup>.

As listed in Chrome's [content scripts documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/content-scripts), the APIs available to a content script are [I have placed deprecated methods in <del>strikethrough</del> format]:

They can access the following extension APIs directly:

> - [`dom`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/dom)
> - [`i18n`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/i18n)
> - [`storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/storage)
> - [`runtime.connect()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#method-connect)
> - [`runtime.getManifest()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#method-getManifest)
> - [`runtime.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#method-getURL)
> - [`runtime.id`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#property-id)
> - [`runtime.onConnect`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#event-onConnect)
> - [`runtime.onMessage`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#event-onMessage)
> - [`runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/runtime#method-sendMessage)

### Extra confusion specifically for `chrome.tabs`

There's additional confusion for `chrome.tabs`. People often assume that because it's `.tabs` and content scripts are in tabs that `chrome.tabs` is available in content scripts, but it's not.

The top banner on the [`chrome.tabs` documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs) says:

> Note: The Tabs API can be used by the service worker and extension pages, but not content scripts.

#### Particular confusion for `chrome.tabs.getCurrent()`

The confusion for `chrome.tabs.getCurrent()` is enhanced, as [the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs#method-getCurrent) says:

> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. Returns undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example, a background page or popup view).

Many people make the assumption that mentioning "non-tab context (for example, a background page or popup view)" it means a non-background context, but the documentation is specifically meaning an *actual* background page, not anything in the background context. What it's meaning is that in order to return the [`tab`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs#type-Tab) it needs to be called from a script that is both in the background context and a tab context. If it's called from a script that's in the background context that's not also in a tab context, then it will return `undefined`. It is not available from a content script context. Attempting to call `chrome.tabs.getCurrent()` from a content script context will result in a

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

which is the error this question is asking about.

### Partition your extension into background scripts and content scripts

You are going to need to separate your code into what needs to be in a background script and what needs to be in content scripts, based on the capabilities available to each type of script. Content scripts have access to the DOM of the web page into which they are injected, but limited access to extension APIs. Background scripts have full access to the extension APIs, but no access to web page content. You should read the [Chrome extension overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview), and the pages linked from there, to get a feel for what functionality should be located in which type of script.

It is common to need to communicate between your content scripts and background scripts. To do so you can use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). This allows you to communicate information between the two scripts to accomplish things which are not possible using only one type of script.
For instance, in your content script, you may need information which is only available from one of the other Chrome APIs, or you need something to happen which can most appropriately (or only) be done through one of the other Chrome extension APIs.  In these cases, you will need to [send a message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to your background script, using [`chrome.runtime.sendMessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage), to tell it what needs to be done, while providing enough informaiton for it to be able to do so. Your background script can then return the desired information, if any, to your content script.  Alternately, you will have times when the processing will primarily be done in the background script.  The background script may inject a content script, or just message an already injected script, to obtain information from a page, or make changes to the web page.

---

1. Background script means any script that is in the background context. In addition to actual [`background` scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages), this includes popups and options pages, etc. However, the only page that you can be sure to have consistently available to receive messages from a content script are your actual [`background` scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) defined in *manifest.json*. Other pages may be available at some times as a result of the user's interaction with the browser, but they are not available consistently.

<sup>This answer was moved from a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679991/chrome-tabs-executescript-is-not-working), and then modified.</sup>

Comment: getCurrent
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function callback)
*Gets the tab that this script call is being made from.* May be undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example, a background page or popup view).

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent

Comment: @GregDomjan `chrome.tabs` is only available in the background context. Content scripts are not in the background context and don't have `chrome.tabs` available. It's possible to open HTML pages that are in your extension within a tab. The most common is options pages, but you can have others. These will be in the background context and have a tab associated with them, which can be obtained from [`chrome.tabs.getCurrent()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent).

Comment: @Makyen That was a direct quote from the docs that you are contradicting. The docs do seem to be wrong at least on the surface, but it would help to acknowledge and address the (apparent) contradiction.

Comment: @AdamSpiers There is no contradiction. The top of the [`chrome.tabs` documentation page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/tabs) very explicitly states "Note: The Tabs API can be used by the service worker and extension pages, **but not content scripts**." So, *everything* on that page excludes the content script context. I have edited this answer to add a section specifically about the confusion generated by those statements in the docs.

Comment: I saw that statement at the top of the page, but I was referring to confusion caused by the section _within_ the page which  @GregDomjan quoted. I think the answer I was looking for (and others were too) to resolve what I described as an apparent contradiction, was that the words "this script call" in that quote refer to other scripts than content scripts. Although since it explicitly excludes background pages and popup views in that quote, and excludes content scripts at the top of the page, it's less obvious which scripts it's implicitly referring to. Thanks for adding the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected shows

> ## getSelected
>
> chrome.tabs.getSelected(integer windowId, function
>   callback)
>   **Deprecated since Chrome 33. Please use tabs.query {active: true}.**
>   Gets the tab that is selected in the specified window.

Maybe, you should use chrome.tabs.query in ***popup.js*** like this

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    console.log(tabs[0].url);
});
```

, **reload** your extension and check the result in the inspect element of your extension.

#### [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFFJ8.png)

#### [code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcTEn.png)

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab shows that 
**The URL the tab is displaying. This property is only present if the extension's manifest includes the "tabs" permission.**(Just for remind someone forgot. I was forgot it when I just test it.)

Comment: No, the problem is that tabs API is **totally unavailable from injected content script**.

Answer (score -3):

Check this answer also https://stackoverflow.com/a/6718277/449345
This one worked for me

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab){
    console.log(tab);
});
```

Comment: The getSelected() chrome.tabs method has been deprecated since Chrome 33