# All chrome.tabs present the same error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make an extension that reloads a tab every 2 minutes, but I want it to try and reload even if the internet was offline (so it would reload when it went back on). Using location.reload() doesn't work when the window gives an error (e.g. offline), so I figured the best way was using chrome.tabs.reload().

The problem is, all chrome.tabs give me a similar error, if I try with an empty argument it should work, since it defaults to the current tab according to the documentation, but instead:

```
chrome.tabs.reload({});
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reload' of undefined
```

If I try to get the current tab ID:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
  console.log(tabs[0]);
});
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'query' of undefined
```

And similarly, every single `chrome.tabs` has a similar error, "Cannot call xxyyzz of undefined". It's as if chrome couldn't see my tabs, what's going on?

My manifest.js is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test",
  "description": "",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"],
      "js": ["reload.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"

    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs","storage","http://www.google.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [chrome.tabs returns undefined in content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You [cannot access](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) `chrome.tabs` from inside a content script,

> [...] content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:

- Use chrome.* APIs (except for parts of chrome.extension) *e.g chrome.tabs*
- Use variables or functions defined by their extension's pages
- Use variables or functions defined by web pages or by other content scripts

> [...]

You have to use a `Background Page` to use the `chrome.tabs` [Api Methods](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html).

And invoke `reload` from there.

**Update:**
*I added a simple sample `background.js` which toggles Autoreloading for a tab (2 Minutes) through a contextmenu click.  I tried to comment it as well as i can*

Spoiler Warning:
Do **not** click [this link](http://pastebin.com/mgcQXf1Q) if you do this as a learning practice *(or anything similar)* for yourself otherwise feel free to do whatever you want with the code

Comment: Whoa, thanks a lot :) I actually had figured out a little bit before your last edit, but your solution worked beautifully and better than mine.

Really thanks.

Comment: You're welcome =), I'm glad if I could help you on getting started with chrome extension development =)
I wish you the best with future projects