# Chome Extension, list its directory entries

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to develop a chrome extension but I occurred in a problem.

I need to list the entries of a directory inside of the extension itself, but, when I try to implement the `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {}` the console notifies me with a **chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry is not a function**.

```
function getImage(callback) {
  chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry(function(root) {
    root.getDirectory("images", {create: false}, function(localesdir) {
      var reader = localesdir.createReader();
      // Assumes that there are fewer than 100 locales; otherwise see DirectoryReader docs
      reader.readEntries(function(results) {
        callback(results.map(function(de){return de.name;}).sort());
      });
    });
  });
}

getImages(function(data){console.log(data);});
```

I post the manifest.json too

```
{
  "name": "My ext",
  "version":"1.1",
  "manifest_version":3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://mysite.dev:*/*"
      ],
      "css": ["content.css"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["images/*.png","images/*.gif"]
}
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You cannot access `chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry` from a content script. Only from a background or popup script. Apart from that, you name your function `getImage`  but call it using `getImages`. Another thing: `manifest_version` should be 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome.tabs returns undefined in content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script)