# browser.tabs.query not completing in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I created a firefox extension which contains a content script namely with the following code:

```js
function onGridClick(e) {
    if (logToConsole) console.log("Grid icon got clicked:" + e.type);
    let id = e.target.parentNode.id;
    if (logToConsole) console.log("Search engine clicked:" + id);
    let nav = document.getElementById("cs-grid");
    nav.style.display = "none";
    nav.removeEventListener("click", onGridClick);
    nav.removeEventListener("mouseleave", onLeave);
    nav = null;
    // Get the tab position of the active tab in the current window
    let tabIndex = 0;
    browser.tabs.query({active:true}).then(function (tab){
        if (logToConsole) console.log(tab);
        tabIndex = tab.index;
        sendMessage("doSearch", {"id": id, "index": tabIndex});
    }, onError);
}
```

The complete content script may be found over at github, [here](https://github.com/odebroqueville/contextSearch/blob/master/scripts/selection.js).

The first two console.logs are executed without any problem, but the 3rd one after the browser.tabs.query never gets output to the console. I tried replacing browser.tabs.query with browser.tabs.getCurrent, but to no avail!

sendMessage is a function that sends a message to the background script.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#WebExtension_APIs)

Only a limited number of WebExtension APIs are available from content scripts and tabs is not one of them!

This information applies to Firefox, but I found [this helpful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034859/chrome-tabs-returns-undefined-in-content-script) on Stackoverflow which applies to Chrome.