# Chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener is throwing a typeerror of undefined - why?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to listen for a tab change using the `onActivated` event listener in the chrome.tabs API. It seems striaight forward, and I'm pretty sure that my code is right, but this error is being thrown: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'onActivated' of undefined
    at window.onload` 
I think it is because my `window.onload` function is async, but I'm not sure. Heres my relevant code in my **content script**:

```
 window.onload = async function () {
        var onOffVal = await getOnOffValue();
            chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function() {
                 if (onOffVal) {
                      //stuff
                 } else {
                      //stuff
             }
        })
    }
```

Full question: **Why is the above error being thrown, and how can I fix it?**

Comment: is this in your background script or content script?

Comment: Content script! Thanks for reminding me that I should specify. @NickParsons

Comment: you can't access `chrome.tabs` in the content script: [chrome.tabs returns undefined in content script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15034859)

Comment: Ohhh, that makes a lot of sense. So I should listen in the background script and then send a message to the content script. Thank you!