# How do you open Chrome extension options page from a web page?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My Chrome extension has a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that uses the following to inject HTML into the page:

```
var optionsUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("src/options/options.html"); 
var content = '<a href="' + optionsUrl + '" target="_blank">Options</a>';
```

This produces:

```
 <a href="chrome-extension://gdocgfhmbfbbbmhnhmmejncjdcbjkhfc/src/options/options.html" target="_blank">Options</a>
```

When I click the link, it opens a new browser tab **and nothing more**.

If I paste the href attribute `chrome-extension://gdocgfhmbfbbbmhnhmmejncjdcbjkhfc/src/options/options.html` into the address bar, I see the options page for my Chrome extension displayed correctly.

- **Why doesn't the link work?**
- **Is there some extra permission that I'm missing?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the manifest file insert:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["src/options/options.html"],
```

more info see [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: saved me a lot of time, i've been going crazy over this :)

Answer (score 1):

Updating for Manifest v3. The following worked for me:

```
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "resources": [ "options.html" ],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]
```

Further. I trigger the options page in a content script via:

```
  `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/options.html`
```